# Support offline calling in open fire?

Tags: openfire

I am using astra chat for open fire. I want to have a feature where an online user calls an offline user. in this case i need to use voip from server to his cell.

How do i know about an offline call event on the server?
Does open fire receive such event?

Comment: what do you mean by : **I want to have a feature where an online user calls an offline user**

Comment: So the requirement is let say there are two user on the open fire system. 
If both are online we are able to establish a p2p call between the two when they login via asta chat client.

Now if one of the user is offline, I plan to understand if we get any packet which is an online user initiates a call to talk with offline user. Then we need to pickup, the packet and make a sip , VoIP call to the offline user. So he can pickup a call from his cell.

Thanks